# How unanswered page showing answered questions?

Tags: support

From the name "unanswered" we can guess this page contains only the that question which is not answered by anyone. But there are so many question in this page which having some answer.

Is this a bug or caching issue.

[image]

Am i missing something.

This image for up voted question and answer.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As visibile in the screenshot you show, that page is described to be for *questions with no up-voted or accepted answers*. When a question doesn't have up-voted or accepted answers, it is shown in that page; that is also true when the question doesn't have answers at all.

It can happen an answer has just received an up-vote, and the question is still shown in that page; that is just a matter of caching.

Comment: Thanks i think this page only show question with no answer. Now it clear to me. Can you please let me know it the answer is accepted. Then will it display in this page!

Comment: I think only the question which does not accepted will display in this page.

Comment: As far as I recall, accepting an answer is considered an up-vote. If an answer is up-voted, the question doesn't appear in that list.